# How do i get the focused window title - Mootools Mocha UI

Tags: javascript, mootools

Im editing the file "\source\Window\window.js" from Mootools-Mocha UI so that when a window is focused, the browser changes its title to the mocha-window.

I've already found where I have to do this, I just dont know how can I get the window's title.

I've already tried

> document.title= windowEl.title;

and

> document.title= instance.title;

and

> document.title=  MUI.Windows.title;

with no luck.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: you are still using mochaui? wow. that project is so dead...

Comment: legacy stuff, i know...

Answer (score 2):

Found it:

```
document.title=  instance.options.title;
```